# AlertDialog Error: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

When I click a button in an activity to show an AlertDialog, but got the error.

The code is as below

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_abc, viewGroup, false);
        builder.setView(dialogView);

        btnSubmit = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        btnCancel = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doSomething();
            }
        });
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener((View view) -> alertDialog.dismiss());

        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

**Any idea about this error?** it's not working on both emulated and real phone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void showDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_abc, viewGroup, false);
        builder.setView(dialogView);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        Button btnSubmit = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        Button btnCancel = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //doSomething();
            }
        });
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener((View view) -> alertDialog.dismiss());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  The dialog can be shown, but got the same error after clicking the submit button. No error comes from 'doSomething'.

Comment: In 'doSomething' code, it has "alertDialog.dismiss();", got error here.